# How to insert NaN array into a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to insert an arbitrary number of rows of NaN values within a 2D array at specific places. I'm logging some data from a microcontroller in a .csv file and parsing with python.

The data is stored in a 3 column 2D array like this

```
[(122.0, 1.0, -47.0) (123.0, 1.0, -47.0) (125.0, 1.0, -44.0) ..., 
(39.0, 1.0, -47.0) (40.0, 1.0, -45.0) (41.0, 1.0, -47.0)]
```

The first column is an sequence counter. What I'm trying to do is iterate through the sequence values, diff current and previous sequence number  and insert as many rows with nan as there are missing sequences.

Basically,

```
[(122.0, 1.0, -47.0) (123.0, 1.0, -47.0) (125.0, 1.0, -44.0)]
```

would become

```
[(122.0, 1.0, -47.0) (123.0, 1.0, -47.0) (nan, nan, nan) (125.0, 1.0, -44.0)]
```

However the following implementation of `np.insert` produces an error

```
while (i < len(list[1])):
     pid = list[i][0]
     newMissing = (pid - LastGoodId + 255) % 256
     TotalMissing = TotalMissing + newMissing
     np.insert(list,i,np.zeros(newMissing,1) + np.nan)   
     i = i + newMissing
     list[i][0] = TotalMissing
     LastGoodId = pid
```

> ---> 28                 np.insert(list,i,np.zeros(newMissing,1) + np.nan)
>        29                 i = i + newMissing
>        30                 list[i][0] = TotalMissing
>
> TypeError: data type not understood

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: It is always a good idea to include the error message you get when you say something is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Added now.

Comment: Is the first col sorted? What happens when the first col goes from `125.0` to `39.0`, should we consider those as missing elements in between them? By missing elements, do you always mean in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, the data in the first column is incremental and wraps around 8 bit overflow(0 - 255) so if the first col goes form 125 to 39 it means 168 packets were lost.

Comment: So, we need to pad with 168 NaN rows in that 125 to 39 going case?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's an important piece of info. Please add that into the question.

Comment: So, did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 4):

From the [doc of `np.insert()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arrray([(122.0, 1.0, -47.0), (123.0, 1.0, -47.0), (125.0, 1.0, -44.0)]))
np.insert(a, 2, np.nan, axis=0)
array([[ 122.,    1.,  -47.],
       [ 123.,    1.,  -47.],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan],
       [ 125.,    1.,  -44.]])
```

Comment: Tried 
`np.insert(a, 2, np.nan, axis=0)`
and got the following error message:

`TypeError: expected a readable buffer object`

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

We can use an initialization based approach to handle multiple gaps and gaps of any lengths -

```
# Pre-processing step to create monotonically increasing array for first col
id_arr = np.zeros(arr.shape[0])
id_arr[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr[:,0])<0)+1] = 256
a0 = id_arr.cumsum() + arr[:,0]

range_arr = np.arange(a0[0],a0[-1]+1)
out = np.full((range_arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1]),np.nan)
out[np.in1d(range_arr,a0)] = arr
```

Sample run -

```
In [233]: arr      # Input array
Out[233]: 
array([[ 122.,    1.,  -47.],
       [ 123.,    1.,  -47.],
       [ 126.,    1.,  -44.],
       [  39.,    1.,  -47.],
       [  40.,    1.,  -45.],
       [  41.,    1.,  -47.]])

In [234]: out
Out[234]: 
array([[ 122.,    1.,  -47.],
       [ 123.,    1.,  -47.],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan],
       [ 126.,    1.,  -44.],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan], (168 NaN rows)
       .....
       [  nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  39.,    1.,  -47.],
       [  40.,    1.,  -45.],
       [  41.,    1.,  -47.]])
```

**Approach #2**

An alternative approach could be suggested to handle such generic cases using `np.insert` instead of initialization, like so -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.in1d(range_arr,a0))
out = np.insert(arr,idx - np.arange(idx.size),np.nan,axis=0)
```