# Append list in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this.

```
lst=[[0, 0.05],
 [1, 0.02],
 [3, 0.02],
 [5, 0.01]]
```

I want to add the missing lists in the list to get this.

```
lst=[[0, 0.05],
 [1, 0.02],
 [2, 0.01],
 [3, 0.01],
 [4, 0.005],
 [5, 0.005]]
```

Here, `[2,x2]` added between `[1,x1]` and `[3,x3]` and `x2=x3/2` and `x3=x2` is performed. Same is to be done for `[4, x4]`.

I have tried this.

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i][0]!=i:
        lst1=[]
        lst1.append(i)
        lst1.append(lst[i+1][1]/2)
        lst.append(lst1)
```

This code is unable to keep track of the element being iterated and adds duplicates and wrong values.

Comment: What about adding the lists and then sorting them with: sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])

Comment: Can you explain the logic for the second value on each row and why the value of the existing [3, 0.02] entry changes to [3, 0.01] in your expected result.

Comment: How do I add the lists though ? The 2nd value in each list depends on the next value (half of it). The next value then becomes same as the previous one. Simply put, any missing list shares the value of the next list uniformly.

Comment: @AlainT. hope the previous comment answered your question.

Comment: You will always skip one value only? Or you can have something like `[[1, 0.4], [5, 04]]`?

Comment: @Valentino The input can have only one missing value at once. So the 1st elements of the lists inside can be 0,1,2,4,6,7,9 etc., but can't be 0,1,4,7 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only one missing value at once, this should work:

```
lst=[[0, 0.05],
 [1, 0.02],
 [3, 0.02],
 [5, 0.01]]

finlst = [lst[0]]
for ll in lst[1:]:
    lind = finlst[-1][0]
    if ll[0] - lind == 1:
        finlst.append(ll)
    else:
        finlst.extend([[lind+1, ll[1]/2], [lind+2, ll[1]/2]])
```

`finlst` is: `[[0, 0.05], [1, 0.02], [2, 0.01], [3, 0.01], [4, 0.005], [5, 0.005]]`.

And since we are here, I propose a more general solution working also in case where there is more than one missing value.

```
finlst = [lst[0]]
for ll in lst[1:]:
    lastind = finlst[-1][0]
    toadd = ll[0] - lastind
    for i in range(toadd):
        finlst.append([lastind+i+1, ll[1]/toadd])
```

Comment: I think you want `finlst.append([lastind+i+1, ll[1] / (2**(toadd-i))])`

Comment: @Ashargin No, why? I should divide the value `ll[1]` for the number of extra list created, which is simply `toadd`.

Comment: This worked on my actual input list. So, I'll go for this for now.

Comment: @Valentino it is not clear what the user wants for when gaps are wider than only 1 row at once. From my understanding the *2 factor had to be repeated but nothing is clearly said for that case so your guess is as good as mine if not better

Comment: @Ashargin it seems he wants half the value because he's dealing with lists where only one element is missing. Sort of normalization. Hence in a more general case, I divide by the number of list added +1, which is `toadd`. That's what I thought.

Comment: @Valentino Yes I generalized the rule some other way but we can't know which is true in the user's head

Comment: @Ashargin yes, I agree on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a list comprehension:

```
r=lst[:1]+[[k+1,v/(j-i)] for (i,_),(j,v) in zip(lst,lst[1:]) for k in range(i,j)]
print(r) # [[0, 0.05], [1, 0.02], [2, 0.01], [3, 0.01], [4, 0.005], [5, 0.005]]
```

Or using procedural code:

```
r = lst[:1]
for j,v in lst[1:]:
    i = r[-1][0]
    for k in range(i,j):
        r.append([k+1,v/(j-i)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with numpy arrays:

```
# append the two lists together
append_lst = np.append(np.array(lst), np.array(missing_lst), axis=0)
# sort by first column
append_lst[append_lst[:,0].argsort()]
```

Where

```
lst=[[0, 0.05],
 [1, 0.02],
 [3, 0.02],
 [5, 0.01]]
```

and

```
missing_lst=[[2, 0.01],
 [4, 0.005]]
```

Output:

```
array([[0.   , 0.05 ],
       [1.   , 0.02 ],
       [2.   , 0.01 ],
       [3.   , 0.02 ],
       [4.   , 0.005],
       [5.   , 0.01 ]])
```

Comment: Well, I don't have a missing list. It has to be derived.

Comment: Let me try to derive the missing list and then use your method.

Comment: you can also use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848990/5094841. Just trying to get working myself, e.g. insert nan when the value is missing and then you'll be able to apply a mask and replace the nan with the value you want

Comment: This is not what the user wants, you're sorting along axis 0 for each column independantly and there is no reason that it would be equal to the rule the user wants to implement

Answer (score 1):

It may not be how you want to do it exactly but I am going to propose a slight deviation to your code.

What about :

```
mydict = {0: 0.05,
          1: 0.02,
          3: 0.02,
          5: 0.01}
for i in range(max(mydict.keys()) - 1, min(mydict.keys()), -1):
    if i not in mydict.keys():
        mydict[i] = mydict[i + 1] / 2
        mydict[i + 1] = mydict[i + 1] / 2
lst = sorted(map(list, mydict.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

What fits properly for your question is most probably [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

If you want a liniar regression (at the cost of losing accuracy) a piece of code could look like this:

```
 elementsToAdd = list(set([i for i in range(0, lst[-1][0] + 1]) - set([i[0] for i in lst]))

 for e in lst:
    if (e[0] - 1) in elementsToAdd:
       lst.append([(e[0] - 1), e[1] / 2.0]

 lst.sort(key = (lambda x: x[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just build your logic during iteration. I added the ability to handle gaps bigger than 1, but regardless, the code should work just fine either ways.

```
lst=[[0, 0.05],
 [1, 0.02],
 [3, 0.02],
 [5, 0.01]]

prev_idx, prev_val = lst[0] #keeps track of last idx and value seen
result = [[prev_idx, prev_val]]

for idx, val in lst[1:]:
    if (idx - prev_idx) == 1: #no gap, just add values as is
        result.append([idx, val])
    else:
        steps_to_add = idx - prev_idx
        gap_to_fill = (val)/steps_to_add
        for i in range(prev_idx + 1, idx + 1): #iterate and fill upto current idx
            result.append([i, gap_to_fill])        
    prev_idx, prev_val = idx, val

print(result)
#Output:
[[0, 0.05], [1, 0.02], [2, 0.01], [3, 0.01], [4, 0.005], [5, 0.005]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i][0] != i:
        lst[i][1] = lst[i][1] / 2
        lst1 = [lst[i][0] - 1, lst[i][1]]        
        lst.append(lst1)

lst.sort()

print(lst)
```

And the output is:

```
[[0, 0.05],
[1, 0.02],
[2, 0.01],
[3, 0.01],
[4, 0.005],
[5, 0.005]]
```